# Right syntax to adress non contiguous Ranges with variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables, syntax

The goal is to copy a specific non contiguous range e.g.:

```
 Range("C3, F3, G3").Copy
```

But with variable rows instead of hard numbers. (variable = i as Long)

Unfortunately the following code:

```
Dim i as Long
i = 2  
Range("C & i, F & i, G & i").Copy
```

Does not work and I get a runtime error 1004 (Application defined or object defined error). I suppose because I somehow used wrong syntax here.

Is there any way to address non contiguous ranges with variable rows in VBA?

Many thanks!

Comment: You would use `Range("C" & i & ", F" & i & ", G" & i).Copy`

Comment: Great, that works as intended. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current format, you need to put quotation `"` marks around the string parts, and your variables will join to them, or concatenate, using `&` *outside* of the string parts

For example the string `"C & i"` is read literally by the computer "C & i"

But you want it to read "C2"

So you write it like this `"C" & i` where `i` = 2

So for your three cell addresses, you'd use:

```
Range("C" & i & ", F" & i & ", G" & i).Copy
```

This would resolve to the string "C2, F2, G2"

You can also do it like this which you might find neater:

```
Range(cells(i, "C"), cells(i, "F"), cells(i, "G")).Copy
```